# Calculating average from most recent records for all locations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the average ratings for each location using the **most recent** (highest timestamp) records from each user. (if a user’s most recent check-in didn’t include a rating, we would use the most recent rating they provided).

Below is the example of the table I am working with and has many more rows not shown

[image]

This is what I have so far..

```
select t.loc_id, t.loc_name, tm.avgRating
from Table_T as t
inner join (
    select  loc_id, loc_name, avg(cast(rating as decimal)) as avgRating, max(Timestamp) as LatestDate
    from Table_T
    group by  loc_id, loc_name) as tm
on t.loc_id = tm.loc_id and t.Timestamp = tm.LatestDate
```

I feel like I need to use the CASE function to reference the older timestamp if there isn't a rating, but I am having a hard time figuring out where to put it.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and usable sample data, as well as expected results, help us help you. Images of data (without DDL) are almost as useful as images of queries, not what you want in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't seem to factor in the last rating for the user but only finding the overall average. You may  try the following where we use `ROW_NUMBER` ordered by the latest timestamp to determine the most recent non-null rating for that user at the location before finding the average for each location.

```sql
SELECT
     t.loc_id,
     t.loc_name,
     AVG(rating) as avgRating
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.loc_id,
        t.loc_name,
        CAST(rating as DECIMAL(12,2)) rating,
        CASE WHEN rating IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_id,user_id ORDER BY t1.Timestamp DESC) END as rn
    FROM
        Table_T t1
) t
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY
     t.loc_id,
     t.loc_name
```

or

```sql
SELECT
     t.loc_id,
     t.loc_name,
     AVG(rating) as avgRating
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.loc_id,
        t.loc_name,
        CAST(rating as DECIMAL(12,2)) rating,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_id,user_id ORDER BY t1.Timestamp DESC) as rn
    FROM
        Table_T t1
    WHERE rating is NOT NULL
) t
WHERE rn=1
GROUP BY
     t.loc_id,
     t.loc_name
```

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a row-numbering solution for this

I've assumed you actually want the most recent `rating` per location *and* user, which the other answer does not give

```sql
SELECT
  loc_id,
  loc_name,
  AVG(CAST(rating AS decimal(18,2))) AS avgRating,
  MAX([Timestamp]) AS LatestDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_id, loc_name, user_id
          ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) AS rn
    FROM Table_T AS t
    WHERE rating IS NOT NULL
) AS t
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY
  loc_id,
  loc_name;
```